# How to check animated material ui popover with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have problem with testing material UI popover component with Webdriver. I want to show the menu and click element inside.

```
 public void logOut() 
 {

    driver.clickOnElementByXpath(USER_MENU_XPATH);
    driver.clickOnElementByXpath(LOGOUT_BUTTON_XPATH);              
}
```

But it will miss click all the time, because when I want to locate Logout button, menu is not "fully opened" and element is not there. I would like to avoid setting hard wait here.

Please help how do i achieve this ?

Comment: You can wait for the logout to appear using webdriverwait then click on it

Comment: google on `explicit wait`

Comment: Explicit wait is something i would like to avoid.

Comment: create an infinite loop with a boolean flag, do your logic inside catching all exceptions, when it finally works set the flag to break the loop... though explicit wait is the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

From [Selenium Python Bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) do the following:

First wait for the element and the wait for it to be clickable with explicit waits.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "LOGOUT_BUTTON_XPATH"))
    )
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'LOGOUT_BUTTON_XPATH')))

finally:
    element.click()
```

Do something similar